# How to use 'minhash' to handle arrays with all negative elements?

Tags: python

I want to use the LSH method to index the top-k neighbors of an object in a database. Then I encountered the following error when using 'datasketch': ValueError: All-NaN slice encountered.
Is this because the elements of the 14th-row vector in my database (a 5000*6 array) are all negative?
Here is my code snippet:

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    M = WeightedMinHashGenerator(Dataset.shape[1])
    LSH_forest = MinHashLSHForest()
    for index, value in enumerate(Dataset): # Where D is a 5000*6 array with values of [-4, 4].
        m_hash = M.minhash(value)
        LSH_forest.add(index,m_hash)

    LSH_forest.index()
    LSH_kneighbors = []
    time_start2 = time.perf_counter()
    for j in range(Q.shape[0]):    # Q is the column to be sequenced
        LSH_kneighbors.append(LSH_forest.query(M.minhash(Q[j]),10))
```

I noticed that the first 13 lines of Q are working, and the fourteen lines have an error:

---

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\Z.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.10.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy_*main*_.py", line 39, in  cli.main()

File "c:\Users\Z.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.10.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 430, in main run()

File "c:\Users\Z.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.10.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 284, in run_file runpy.run_path(target, run_name="**main**")

File "c:\Users\Z.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.10.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy_vendored\pydevd_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 321, in run_path return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,

File "c:\Users\Z.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.10.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy_vendored\pydevd_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 135, in _run_module_code_run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,

File "c:\Users\Z.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.10.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy_vendored\pydevd_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 124, in _run_code exec(code, run_globals)

File "e:\PythonAlgorithmn\PCD.py", line 95, in  m_hash = M.minhash(value)

File "D:\Anaconda\envs\PCD\lib\site-packages\datasketch\weighted_minhash.py", line 139, in minhash k = np.nanargmin(ln_a)

File "<**array_function** internals>", line 200, in nanargmin

File "D:\Anaconda\envs\PCD\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\nanfunctions.py", line 552, in nanargmin raise ValueError("All-NaN slice encountered")

---

The data is as follows:
[-1.9261107  -2.7339218  -2.3160297  -2.0100772  -2.0696172  -0.79079717].
How should I solve this problem? thank you!
I want to be able to use LSH to index my database.

Comment: Could you post the full error message? And your code as text?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know uploading pictures was not recommended. I updated my question again

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete error report starting with the word **traceback**. You can surround the report with 3` before and 3` after to properly format the output.

Comment: I tried to make the whole data +4 so that all the elements were non-negative, but the result was wrong.

Comment: In addition, I found that the LSH search speed is actually slower than the brute force search speed, which is perverse. I'm not sure what went wrong.